# how to find out session id of executing ssis package through SP_target

Tags: sql-server, sql, database-administration, ssis

I am executing a ssis Package which contains only one data flow task. Simply SELECT statement in source and Table in destination. I want to find out session id of this running Package in SP_TARGET. I need to transfer large amount of data which would take few hours and don't want DBA to kill my Session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_who2 to look for sessions from that hostname (can also check the application name, user name, etc), and you can use dbcc inputbuffer({your pid here}) to grab the text of the input submitted by that pid, to make sure you've got the right pid. However there's no way that I know of to hide your session from an admin or prevent it from being killed.

It might be easier to just ask the DBA not to kill your session.